# Axiom of Foundation and least element

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Axiom of Foundation also defined as:
>
> - A set contains no infinitely descending (membership) sequence.
> - A set contains a (membership) minimal element
>
> [source](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Axiom:Axiom_of_Foundation)

Do I understand correctly that for each set there should be the smallest element?

For the set of Natural numbers the minimal element is 0.

Can you please explain what is the minimal element from the set of Integers and Real numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimal does not mean "minimal in an arbitrary order". It means in the $\in$ membership relation.

So to answer that, you'd need to first tell us how you have interpreted $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb R$ as sets.

In the usual constructions you'll end up with a situation that no real number is an element of another (and the same about $\Bbb Z$), and in that case, they are all $\in$-minimal.

Comment: Understand. May I ask you more philosophical question. Imagine we live in a Universe that can be described by Set theory language. All objects in this Universe are elements of some Super set. Does it mean that there should exist the smallest atom (∈-minimal)?

Comment: Yes. But in a lot of cases, you have a lot of minimal elements, so for example you can have that all elementary particles are $\in$-minimal. But this is like asking what is the content of the middle bit of your RAM card. It's kind of irrelevant for everything you're actually doing. Foundation is very important to set theory itself, but not much beyond that (it comes up here and there, but very very rarely).

Comment: Do I understand correctly that following this idea there is possibility for theological speculations: there exists unique ∈-minimal element and it is God? Similar to idea of Pantheism.

Comment: NO. NO. NO. NO. NO. NO.